Including `.jinja` template files inside the Python distribution using `pyproject.toml`
I'm working on a package. It has a console command that enables users to generate a template from the .jinja files within the distribution.
My issue is that I can't include them (template files) in my distribution. Here is a tree-look of my package and where my templates are located. (template/)
mypack/
├── mypack/
│   ├── package1/
│   ├── package2/
│   └── template
│       └── {{tmpl_slug}}
│           └── file1.py.jinja
│           └── file2.json.jinja
│           └── config.yml
│           └── ...
└── pyproject.yml

I want my distribution to have the exact template/ directory with all its sub-files and sub-directories.
I can do what I need using a MANIFEST.in file that has the following single line in it.
graft mypack/template

How can I do it without the MANIFEST file, just via pyproject.toml?!
